# Inserting option elements in a dynamic dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a dynamic dropdown selection using [this theme](https://github.com/codrops/SelectInspiration) with Javascript. The `<option>` elements are taken from an array in a text file using AJAX and inserted in the `<select>` dropdown:

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cs-select.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cs-skin-border.css" />
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/array.txt",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
        }
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        var myArray = JSON.parse(data);

var output = [];
            $.each(myArray, function(key, value)
            {
              output.push('<option value="' + value + '">'+ value +'</option>');
            });
            $('#myselect').html(output.join(''));
        });
</script>
```

And here's the HTML part:

```
     <body>
         <form id="myform" action="select.php">
            <input id="myinput" name="owncategory" type="text"> <br><br>
            <div>
                <select class="cs-select cs-skin-border" id="myselect">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a category</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div><input id="mysubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
        </form>

        <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
        <script src="js/selectFx.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function() {
                    new SelectFx($(".cs-select").get(0));
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
```

The problem is, the dropdown selection (which is now stylized by the script) doesn't show the added `<option>` elements, even though when the page is inspected on a browser, they're there. I don't know how to show them as part of the stylized dropdown. Any ideas?

EDIT: I just figured it out, kind of. So instead of inserting it on the select element with the `#myselect` id:

```
$('#myselect').html(output.join(''));
```

I inserted it on a `<div>` element that shows up when the page loads:

```
$('.cs-options').html(output.join(''));
```

And now I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zav88.png

But now my current problem is that they're un-selectable.

Comment: can u provided us demo?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. **[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/2L70r9ey/)**. May be the data is not coming proper.. can you just `console.log(data)` and paste it in question?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao said is true

Comment: @fiidofirdauz Here's my page: [link](http://i.imgur.com/RbGKVxI.png) (don't mind the "Ajax Test" and "Submit" buttons). And here's the console from the browser: [link](http://i.imgur.com/xPk3QMi.png). As you can see, the option elements are there. They are taken from a text file, using this code:

`$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/array.txt",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
        }
    })`
But when I click on the dropdown, they don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Work for me.

```
<li data-option="" data-value="therock" class=""><span>The rock</span></li>
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if it's `<li>` instead of `<option>`?